# How should I deal in correct way with recuring events and possible events' details? (Mongo,Vue)

Tags: mongodb, vue.js, sails.js, backend, database

I am struggling with the way how I should design scheme for my data.
I saw a lot of threads with recuring calendar events but I can't translate it into my case as it is slightly different and this small difference making it tough.
Basically I have two models which don't let me sleep. EVENT and EVENT_DETAILS
First of all, I am using MongoDB but this is mostly more high level abstraction than going down to DB level, but I can be wrong.
Backend is SailsJS.
On the frontend I have VueJS SPA.

I have events. Most of them are recuring forever (permanent), but some of them are either one off, so have exact date when they happen,
some of them are recuring on one day of week in given period and some of permanent are suspended for given period.

EVENT can exist without EVENT_DETAILS, but not the other way of course.

I need to let user go through WEEKS periods and be able to see list of EVENTS in given period and related EVENT_DETAILS and if there is no EVENT_DETAILS,
let him create it.

For handling permanent, suspension and temporary, I have following attributes in

```
my EVENT (I show only relevant atts):
TYPE: [0,1,2]; 0 - permanent, 1 - temp, 2 - one off
SUSPENDED: true/false
SUSPENSION_DATES (from,to)
PERIOD (from,to) - for temporary
DAY: [0-6] - day of the week (choosen for 0 and 1, autmatically for 2 - one off
```

and of course association to EVENT_DETAILS.

Is it ok or should I amend it to make it correct/better/easier to deal with ?

How should I handle criteria to give user complete list of events for particular period?
I am of course not asking for code as it is not an issue for me. 
I am asking for help with logic/criteria as I am really stuck with that for few days.

Comment: One event can have zero or more details, each of which is a string? And you're storing the details in another schema, right?

Comment: details is an model, associated with event.

Answer (score 1):

A few improvements you may consider:

- since your events are specified by the unit of day, events happening on one day and those last for a period can be normalized into one, by setting start and end dates to the same for one-off events.
- As for a field in a schema in mongodb, not only primitive types are allowed, objects/arrays can also be used to form complicated structures. So you can just store an event's details in the event schema, with a field of array of strings, like `{type: [String], default: []}` in mongoose syntax, or even `{type: [{label: String, description: String}], default: []}`.

For the second bullet, embedding documents in mongodb is good for forming a model-like database structure, but mongodb doesn't do really well in aggregation, so only embed those "belonging" to a schema (or, those with a one-one or multi-one relation mapping to another, not multi-multi), in our case here, it should be safe to do so since details belong to single events.

So now there's just events in periods and weekly events, which can't be normalized into one since one is continous and the other is not. Having a `type` flag to identify them seems all right to me. You can make some comments/documents and add some configs like `const EVENT_TYPES = {PERMANENT: 0, TEMP: 1}` and use these readable type configs instead of `0` `1`s to make sure your colleages and yourself won't hate you in the future ;)